# Holomorphic function on the unit disk $f$, show the set $z,w\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=f(w)$ is not countable

Tags: complex-analysis, analyticity

Here is the problem statement:

Suppose $f$ is a holomorphic function on the unit disk. Show that the set $A=\lbrace (z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2\;|\; |z|,|w| \leq \frac{1}{2}, z\neq w, f(z)=f(w)\rbrace$ is either finite or uncountably infinite.

I'm pretty stuck, but here are some thoughts:

1. The bound on the $z,w$ is a ltitle odd. The only thing I take away from it is that $|z+w| \leq |z| + |w| = 1$ so the sum stays in the closure of the disk. But this doesn't seem relevant.
2. I tried to find a clever way to use the identity principle but I couldn't. For example, suppose to the contrary the set $A$ is countably infinite, then it is pointless to consider the function $g(z) = f(z) - f(w_0)$ for some $w_0 \in A$ since there doesn't need to be countably many $z_0$ matching up with $w_0$ in the sense $f(z_n) = f(w_0)$, only countably many pairs $z,w$ with the same images.
3. I tried representing $f(z)$ as a power series centered at $z_0=0$:
   $$
   f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n
   $$
   and then considering expressions like
   $$
   f(z_0) - f(w_0) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z_0^n - w_0^n)
   $$
   to learn something about the coefficients but this didn't lead anywhere.

I think there must be some slick solution but I can't see it, so I'd prefer hints rather than full solutions right now.

Comment: I suppose you also want $z \neq w$?

Comment: Yeah, that should probably be in there, thanks.

Comment: It's easy to use the Open Mapping Theorem to reduce to the case $|z| = |w| = 1/2$.  The problem then becomes one of how many times an analytic image of the circle can intersect itself without crossing.  I'm pretty sure $1/2$ could be replaced by anything in $(0,1)$.

Comment: My intuition says that if $A$ is infinite, then it has an accumulation point somewhere, and you can somehow prove (using holomorphicness of $f$ presumably) that there is a whole neighborhood of that accumulation point contained in $A$, thus un-countably many points. I don't know what to do if the accumulation point happens to be on the diagonal.

Comment: Kudos on the "show your work" part.

Answer (score 3):

I believe I may have a proof that uses well-known results about holomorphic functions of several complex variables and the [Baire Category Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem).

First, recall that zeros of holomorphic functions of more than one variable are not isolated. This is a consequence of a well known theorem due to Hartogs. Now, suppose that $A$ is countable, say $A=\{(z_1,w_1),(z_2,w_2),\dots\}$. The set
$$S:=\{(z,w) : |z|,|w| \leq  1/2 : f(z)=f(w)\}$$ is closed, and we have
$$S= \{(z,z):|z| \leq 1/2\} \cup \{(z_1,w_1)\} \cup \{(z_2,w_2)\} \cup \dots.$$
By the Baire Category Theorem, one of the sets in the union has non-empty interior. Clearly it cannot be the diagonal, and so we have that one of the points $(z_j,w_j)$ is isolated in $S$. But this point would be an isolated zero of the holomorphic function $g(z,w):=f(z)-f(w)$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: Seems correct, but it also seems rather overkill to invoke the Hartogs theorem for a proof of a result about a function of one complex variable.

Comment: +1 Nice answer! But I should have mentioned this in the question: this is from a qualifying exam given after a one semester course in real analysis and analysis of functions of one complex variable. Can you think of a similar proof using more elementary means? I had a feeling it had something to do with what you call $g(z,w)$.

Comment: @unit3000-21 : I've thought about a more elementary proof but I can't find one. I'll keep thinking about it though... Interesting problem!

Comment: @MalikYounsi Thanks very much.  I'll continue to think about it too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that was pointed out to me by a fellow student:

The claim is that the set is either *empty* or uncountable, in fact. Assume there is one such pair $(z,w) \in A$ such that $f(z) = f(w)$. But since $\mathbb{C}$ is Hausdorff, we can separate each point by an open set such that the open sets are disjoint: $z\in U, w\in V, U\cap V = \varnothing$.

But by the open mapping theorem, the image contains a ball around $f(z)=f(w)$ which is contained in $f(U) \cap f(V)$. That is, $f(U)$ is open, $f(V)$ is open and they have a nontrivial intersection which must too be open and thus contains a ball $B$ which contains $f(z)=f(w)$.

Now we pick some other point $f(z) \neq \alpha \in B$. Then $f^{-1}(\alpha) \supset  \lbrace z_0 \neq z\in U, w_0 \neq w \in V \rbrace$ where $f(z_0) = f(w_0)$. Thus, $f^{-1}(B) \subset A$ where $f^{-1}(B)$ is uncountable.

Thus, if there is one point in $A$, there are uncountably many points in $A$.

Comment: I had thought about this too, but I don't think it works. The problem is that it may happens that your $z,w$ satisfy $|z|=|w|=1/2$. In this case, $f^{-1}(\alpha)$ indeed contains points different than $z,w$, but these points may be outside the closed disk centered at $0$ of radius $1/2$, and so these points do not belong to $A$. See Robert Israel's comment.